# Root file browser for raspbian jessie

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, root

Is there any way to open root file browser in raspbian (like `gksudo nautilus` in ubuntu)?

Comment: What are you trying to do with a root file browser? It may be easier and potentially safer from the command line.

Comment: You can always install gksudo on Raspbian: `sudo apt-get install gksu` should work.

Comment: I need to modify some system file. @SteveRobillard

Comment: I tried the command `gksu` but it is saying 'Xlib:  extension `"RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".'`

Comment: try this from the command line sudo nano filenametobemodified obviously using the file you need to modify

Comment: I agree with Steve.  It is much better to use that kind of command line.  Simply opening the file manager as root will let you rename files and such but it will not allow you to click-to-edit since the edit program (nano, leafpad, vi) will not run as su.  What would REALLY help with this is a simple "open in terminal" from file-manager - then issue the `sudo vi filename` just like in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Typing `gksudo` in **Terminal** and then hitting enter. A window named **Run program** will pop up.

Then typing `pcmanfm` on the **Run** text field. Pressing ok.

That worked for me.

[image: img 1]

Comment: Excellent.  Good for file renaming and such.  However, when you click to open a file in vi or leafpad it still won't save back to it.

Answer (score 16):

1. Open the Terminal
2. Type `sudo pcmanfm`

The root file manager opens.

Answer (score 4):

You will find that 'mc' ( midnight commander ) is the fastest for browsing and file operations - CTRL+o will give you a root shell prompt to view output of commands. On a Pi, it's lightweight. You don't want to swap to your microSD. Invoke `apt-get -y install mc' . A number of common operations are 'hit-one-key-and-presto!' on the **F**unction keys .

Answer (score 2):

Just start your file manager as root.

Let's say your file manager is *pcmanfm*, then you should run these commands

```
pi@mypi:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for pi: 

root@mypi:/home/pi# pcmanfm 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

Comment: why not simply `sudo pcmanfm`?

Comment: In the case of accessing Environment Variables of root,  user space should be changed. We can not know which variables are needed by the running process (i.e. pcmanfm).

Comment: Actually we can know that if we check [`man pcmanfm`](https://www.mankier.com/1/pcmanfm). Your approach will replace desktop and menu entries with the ones from `root` user, if corresponding variables are configured in `/root/.bashrc`. I don't really see the benefit.

Comment: I don't mean that we can not know variables specifically required by  _pcmanfm_.  I mean that to forget about this kind of concerns for **ANY** process we want to run, we should run it after _sudo su_ in a generic/nonspecific manner.

Answer (score 2):

Running `sudo file-manager` should be enough to start whatever file manager you have configured. Depending on your setup, you may need to run `xhost +` as the user who owns the desktop, to allow root processes to connect to it.

Finally, if your X configuration is really bizarre, you might need to tell the file manager which display it should use, i.e. `sudo DISPLAY=:0 file-manager`. Note that this should not be necessary in a normal setup.